# facebook page lands on the bottom. need it land on the top

Tags: html, css, facebook

I am building a facebook app ....

When one fills the first page form after clicking like, the thank you page is loaded. However it loads such that it goes to the bottom. After pressing submit we land on the Thank you Page ...But I land at the bottom of the page, not the top. How to make it land on the top?

http://on.fb.me/1iyj6ZQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The surrounding Facebook page does not automatically scroll anywhere when you replace the pages inside your app iframe. To do so, you have to call [FB.Canvas.scrollTo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.scrollTo/) after your new page is loaded.

I generally include that in all pages of my apps, so that whenever the user switches to another sub-page the whole FB page always gets scrolled to the top again.